# A possible implementation of std::rotate

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've implemented this rotate_ algorithm mimicking STL's : The algorithm left-shifts all the elements n times where n is the distance between the first element and the axis (middle):

```
template <typename InIt>
InIt rotate_(InIt first, InIt Rit, InIt last){
    if(first == last)
       return last;
    if(Rit == first)
       return first;

    auto tmp = Rit;

    while( Rit != first ){
       auto it = first;
       while( std::next(it) != last ){
           iter_swap_(it, std::next(it) );
           ++it;
       }
       Rit = std::prev(Rit);
   }
   return first + distance(tmp, last);
}

int main(){

   vector<int> v1{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
   vector<int> v2(v1);
   int index = 3;
   auto it1 = rotate(v1.begin(), v1.begin() + index, v1.end());
   auto it2 = rotate_(v2.begin(), v2.begin() + index, v2.end());

   if(it1 != v1.cend())
       cout << *it1 << " : " << it1 - v1.cbegin() << '\n';
   if(it2 != v2.cend())
       cout << *it2 << " : " << it2 - v2.cbegin() << '\n';

   for(int i : v1)
       cout << i << ", ";
   cout << '\n';

   for(int i : v2)
       cout << i << ", ";
   cout << '\n';

 }
```

The output:

```
1 : 5
1 : 5
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3,
```

The output is identical but I want to know whether there's a better implementation or some bugs in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `distance` is missing the `std::` qualifier.
- `first + ...` assumes a random access iterator. It is an unnecessary requirement. A bulk of the code requires bidirectional iterators only. Try to stay with them.
- Performance-wise the algorithm has \$O(nk)\$ time complexity (\$n\$ being the size of the range, and \$k\$ a shift amount). The worst case is of course quadratic. Meanwhile, there are linear algorithms.

PS: what is `iter_swap_` (with the trailing underscore)?

Comment: In fact in my code I am using 'using namespace std;' that is why i don't qualify names. `iter_swap_` is my version of `std::iter_swap` because I am implementing my STL-like library for practice purpose only. Thank you.